# java - query extended properties from active directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to retrieve information from an active directory. It is working so far except I am not able to retrieve extended properties.

LDAP search filter:

```
String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(employeeId=*))";
String searchBase = "dc=DOM,dc=TLD";
String returnedAtts[]={"userPrincipalName"}; 
searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts); 

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ldapContext.search(searchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);
while (answer.hasMoreElements()) 
{ 
    SearchResult sr = (SearchResult)answer.next(); 
    Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes(); 

    System.out.println(attrs.get("userPrincipalName"));
    System.out.println(attrs.get("employeeId"));
}
```

Unfortunately I can retrieve only the default properties. How can I retrieve the extended properties? 
Is there anything wrong with the code or did I forget something? Are the extended properties depending on user permissions?

Answer (score 1):

finally i solved it by adding the property names to the returning attributes:

```
String returnedAtts[]={"userPrincipalName","department","employeeID","mail"}; 
searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
```